# Value Present in a Range or Not

Tags: r

I want to check whether or not a value is within a range or not; if it is present, insert a value; else do nothing.

Say I have some two (or more) vectors,

```
A <- c(1.1, 3.4, 5.5, 10.2)
B <- c(1.1, 3.4, 5.5, 8.01, 10.2)
```

If I look at vector A for the presence of a number in the range 7.8 to 8.2, since there isn't one there I want to insert the number 8.01.

When I look at vector B and test whether or not there is a number in the range 7.8 to 8.2, since one is present; I don't want to do anything.

It looks simple but I'm missing something.  Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: You can use `<` or `>` to find the elements in 'A' or 'B' in that range

Comment: That's where my problem lies ... if one _is_ present that works but what if one isn't?

Comment: I think you could use Akrun's answer with `length` and `if`

Comment: This is Akrun's answer so I won't try to steal credit but `if(length(A[A > 7.8 & A < 8.2]) == 0) A <- c(A, 8.01)`

Comment: @Hack-R You could undelete your answer with that idea.  I don't have any problems in that as I didn't write any code.

Comment: @Hack-R looks like our posts overlapped - I posted as answer just before you posted as comment. I'll delet mine if you want to change your answer

Comment: @Hack-R don't use `length(A[cond])`; it suffices `sum(cond)`.

Comment: When OP says "insert the number 8.01", is the intention to replace at a particular place in the vector or just on the end?

Comment: @PierreLafortune at a particular place.  The numbers are sequential, the insertion should be such that the sequence is kept.  More detail: the numbers are retentions times from a chromatography run ... I want to insert a dummy value at a particular time if the peak is not present.  Do some work on the data.  Remove the dummy variable, this question was my first stumbling block.

Comment: @Nicola very useful to know.  I can see that is what was used in the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this toy function for general implementation. `x` is the input vector, `l` and `u` are lower and upper bound, while `x0` is the value to insert (if insertion turns out needed).

```
foo <- function (x, l, u, x0) {
  z1 <- x > l
  z2 <- x < u
  if (sum(z1 & z2)) x
  else append(x, x0, which(z1)[1] - 1)
  }

A <- c(1.1, 3.4, 5.5, 10.2)
B <- c(1.1, 3.4, 5.5, 8.01, 10.2)

foo(A, 7.8, 8.2, 8.01)
#[1]  1.10  3.40  5.50  8.01 10.20

foo(B, 7.8, 8.2, 8.01)
#[1]  1.10  3.40  5.50  8.01 10.20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( !sum(A > 7.8 & A < 8.2 ) ) A <- c(A, 8.01)
if ( !sum(B > 7.8 & B < 8.2 ) ) B <- c(B, 8.01)
```

If you need to insert the value within the sequence rather than at the end, you can use sort:

```
if ( !sum(A > 7.8 & A < 8.2 ) ) A <- sort(c(A, 8.01))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach through `between` function of `dplyr` package

```
if(!any(dplyr::between(A,7.8,8.2))) A <- c(A,8.01)
if(!any(dplyr::between(B,7.8,8.2))) B <- c(B,8.01)
```